# How to make scrollable div inside a <td>?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this nested table. In one of the `<td>` I'd like to have a scrollable div.

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" style="width:100% !important; font-size:10px; height:inherit;" border'1px'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;width:5% !important;">NO</th>
      <th style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;width:20% !important;">NAME</th>
      <th style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;width:75% !important;">LOCATION</th>
    </tr>                      
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="padding:0px;">
      <td colspan='2' style="padding:0px;">COLUMN 1</td>
      <td style="padding:0px;">
        <div style='width:800px;overflow-x:scroll;'>This DIV should have a large width</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When I insert `800px` as the `div` width, it is displayed correctly. But, If I insert `1000px` the display output is broken. Ideally, I need it up to `5000px`++.

Comment: Try using `max-width` instead of `width` for that `<div>` element

Comment: @Clint_A I've used `max-width` and the output still broken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted. This will keep your requested 5000+px width all the time, while inside a smaller scrollable div. (btw overflow-x: auto; means that it will only show the scrollbar when the content is actually overflowing rather than all the time)

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" style="width:100% !important; font-size:10px; height:inherit;" border'1px'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;width:5% !important;">NO</th>
      <th style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;width:20% !important;">NAME</th>
      <th style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;width:75% !important;">LOCATION</th>
    </tr>                      
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="padding:0px;">
      <td colspan='2' style="padding:0px;">COLUMN 1</td>
      <td style="padding:0px;">
        <div style='width:800px;overflow-x:auto;'>
          <div style='width:5000px;'>This DIV should have a large width</div>
        </div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have your width as 25% and 75% since in your `<thead>` the first two columns account for 25% and the third 75%. So your translate the same to the `<tbody>`

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-bordered" style="width:100% !important; font-size:10px; height:inherit;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;width:5% !important;">NO</th>
      <th style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;width:20% !important;">NAME</th>
      <th style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;width:75% !important;">LOCATION</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="padding:0px;">
      <td colspan='2' style="padding:0px;width:25% !important;">COLUMN 1</td>
      <td style="padding:0px;">
        <div style='width:75% !important;overflow-x:scroll;position:relative;'>This DIV should have a large width</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Each table column have defined width 5%,25% and 75%. Is it possible to insert a very large div (in px)  inside the 75% column?

Comment: I think using percentage widths in the `thead` and `px` widths in the body is what's breaking your table when you use very high widths. If say you force the `div` to have 5000px width - it beats the point of the div being scrollable